# On focus of an input hide label with CSS

Tags: css, forms

I've this form:

```
<div class="c--input">
    <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
    <input id="firstname" type="text">
</div>
```

I would like to remove the `<label>` when user try to insert texte in the input.

So I used this:

```
.c--input input:focus + label::before,
.c--input input:active + label::before {
    opacity: 0;            /* To visually hide the label's pseudoelement */
    pointer-events: none;  /* To prevent any cursor-based interaction */
}
```

Why it does not work ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to focus or active to hide by display none and show by display inline

```
.c--input  label{
  display: inline-block;
}
div input:active + label,
div input:focus + label {
   display: none;
 }
```